# Do Prefetch Tags for iOS On-Demand Resources need to be requested?

Tags: ios, foundation, on-demand-resources

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/Tagging.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH3-SW2) about **Prefetched On-Demand** tags:

> The resources start downloading after the app is installed. The tags
> will be downloaded in the order in which they are listed in the
> Prefetched tag order group.

Do assets designated with Prefetched Tags need to be explicitly requested via `beginAccessingResources` on `NSBundleResourceRequest` (just like regular **Downloaded Only On Demand** tags), or should they automatically download without any explicit code as the docs suggest?

I've tagged several assets with Prefetched Tags but I'm not seeing them automatically downloaded in Debug builds, but if I explicitly request them, they will be downloaded. (I've not yet tested on TestFlight.)

Comment: Did you get an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use Downloaded Only On Demand while in development. You’ll have to deploy the app to the App Store or TestFlight to use the other tag types.